# Как указать длину полосы прокрутки в Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Как указать длину для Scrollbar() в Tk()?

Вот пример кода:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk() 
root.geometry("1280x720")
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root,orient=VERTICAL, elementborderwidth=10, width = 300)
scrollbar.place(relx=.100, rely=.100)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: разве она не относительная?

Comment: Не рекомендуют для полосы прокрутки метод place, лучше используйте grid. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68967384/make-scrollbar-longer-in-tkinter

Comment: @СергейКох в принципе, есть очень мало случаев, когда действительно нужен place.